# How to close one element at a time with the same classes using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to close the individual div at the click of each close icon button to the extreme right of the div.

here is a link of what i did [a link](https://jsfiddle.net/heroxg/snx7kap1/6/)

```js
/* javascript to close new order list for specific order */
var closeNewOrderBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".specificOrder");
for (var x = 0; x < closeNewOrderBtn.length; x++) {
  //add event listener to close button
  closeNewOrderBtn[x].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    var specificOrderList = ev.target.closest(".individualOrder");
    specificOrderList.style.display = "none";
  });
}
/* end javascript to close new order list for specific order */

/* javascript to close new order for all oder at once */
var closeAllOrder = document.querySelectorAll(".closeOrder");
for (var i = 0; i < closeAllOrder.length; i++) {
  closeAllOrder[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var completeOrder = document.querySelectorAll(".closeAllOrder");
    for (var i = 0; i < completeOrder.length; i++) {
      completeOrder[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
/* javascript to close new order for all oder at once */
```

```css
.new-order {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.new-order-body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: none;
}

.new-order-head {
  float: left;
}

.new-order-head a {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.new-order-brief {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px -2px #ddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px -2px #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 22px -2px #ddd;
}

.new-order-brief p {
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 7px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.new-order-brief a {
  color: #f47c11;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span.close-new-order {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: -3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fb2b2b;
}

span.specific {
  color: #fb2b2b;
}

.add-extra {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.add-extra a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.add-extra a:hover {
  background: none;
}

.new-order-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="new-order-body">
  <div class="new-order-wrap">
    <div class="new-order-brief closeAllOrder">
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - 1 plate of rice + chiken - N750</p>
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - extra chiken - N300</p>
      <div class="add-extra">
        <p><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> Add extras</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="close-new-order closeOrder"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></span>
  </div>
  <!-- end new-order-wrap -->
  <div class="new-order-wrap">
    <div class="new-order-brief closeAllOrder">
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - 1 plate of chiken + chips - N600</p>
      <div class="add-extra">
        <p><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> Add extras</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="close-new-order"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o closeOrder"></i></span>
  </div>
  <!-- new-order-wrap -->
  <div class="new-order-wrap">
    <div class="new-order-brief closeAllOrder">
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - 1 plate of rice + chiken - N750</p>
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - extra chiken - N300</p>
      <div class="add-extra">
        <p><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> Add extras</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="close-new-order"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o closeOrder"></i></span>
  </div>
  <!-- end new-order-wrap -->
  <div class="new-order-wrap">
    <div class="new-order-brief closeAllOrder">
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - 1 plate of rice + chiken - N750</p>
      <p class="individualOrder"><span class="specific"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o specificOrder"></i></span> - extra chiken - N300</p>
      <div class="add-extra">
        <p><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span> Add extras</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="close-new-order"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o closeOrder"></i></span>
  </div>
  <!-- end new-order-wrap -->

</div>
<!-- end new order body -->
```

I want each div to close upon click on the close icon button at the top right of each div. with what i have done right now, when you click on a div the entire div closes leaving just the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated link with working solution : https://jsfiddle.net/zc7r65pu/

Key point is finding the parent div using `this` inside the click handler of close button:

```
    var closeAllOrder = document.querySelectorAll(".closeOrder");
    for (var i = 0; i < closeAllOrder.length; i++) {
        closeAllOrder[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
           this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none"
        });
    }
```

Also I would recommend Event Delegation for handling multiple click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

in this line

```
var completeOrder = document.querySelectorAll(".closeAllOrder");
```

your are querying all the `closeAllOrder` classes.

You should query the closest element which has this class.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the `query selector` with parent-element and now it works fine here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c584ah9m/)

```
    closeAllOrder[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var completeOrder = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
            completeOrder.style.display = "none";
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Vishnu Prasad for your reply. it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

For closing the whole order also you use the same method, used for closing single order inside whole order

```
/* javascript to close new order for all oder at once */
var closeAllOrder = document.querySelectorAll(".closeOrder");
for (var i = 0; i < closeAllOrder.length; i++) {
    closeAllOrder[i].addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
        var completeOrder = ev.target.closest('div');
        //for (var i = 0; i < completeOrder.length; i++) {
            completeOrder.style.display = "none";
        //}
    });
}
```

/* javascript to close new order for all oder at once */